# Make an animation repeat X times

Tags: unity, mecanim

I am using Unity Mecanim and I would like an animation ( walking animation about 2 seconds longs ) to repeat X times before moving to the next animation. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to :

1. Create an empty state in the Animator (called `Idle` for example), with a transition to your `Walk` state. Uncheck the `Has exit time` of the transition from `Idle` to `Walk` transition, but leave 1 to the transition from `Walk` to `Idle`.
2. Create a `walkCount` integer parameter in the animator and give it the value of your choice (4 if you want your Walk animation to repeat 4 times)
3. Add a new condition between the transition from `Idle` to `Walk` : `walkCount` greater than 0
4. Add a transition between the "Idle" state and your next animation. Add the condition `walkCount` equals 0.
5. Select the `Walk` state and create a new `StateMachineBehaviour` with the following code :

   ```
   using UnityEngine;

   public class NAME_OF_YOUR_WALK_STATE: StateMachineBehaviour {

        // OnStateEnter is called when a transition starts and the state machine starts to evaluate this state
       override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
           animator.SetInteger( "walkCount", animator.GetInteger("walkCount") - 1 ) ;
       }
   }
   ```

[image: Animator]

---

EDIT : Summary of the comments and chat :

- 3 states and 4 transitions
- States : [Idle] - [Walk] - [NextAnim]
- Transitions :

  - [Idle] → [Walk] : No exit time, walkCount > 0, transition duration = 0
  - [Walk] → [Idle] : Exit time = 1, walkCount > 0, transition duration = 0
  - [Idle] → [NextAnim] : No exit time, walkCount = 0, transition duration = 0
  - [Walk] → [NextAnim] : Exit time = 1, walkCount = 0, transition duration = 0

Comment: the walking animation does get repeated but the idle and the other animation do not work

Comment: it is stuck on the walking animation

Comment: i think the transition from walk to idle needs a condition

Comment: The Idle animation must not have any animation, and the transition from Walk To Idle must not have exit time nor condition.

Comment: oh the idle animation does have an animation

Comment: still doesnt work. WalkCount wont decrease

Comment: Have you added the script I gave you to the "Walk" animator state ?

Comment: yes i add it to the walk state

Comment: walkcount only decreases once

Comment: Nothing should prevent the "flow" to go from "Walk" to "Idle". Are you sure you don't have any condition or settings in the "Walk" state ?

Comment: nothing, only your script

Comment: Oh sorry, the "Walk" state must have an exit time set to 1.

Comment: ok great walk count decreases but it keeps going to idle after walk 4 times. So the animation kind of glitches

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61457/discussion-between-casanova-and-hellium).

Comment: Then, try to make a transition from `Walk` to your next animation with the condition "walkCount" equals 0